# Where does windows 7 get its monitor names?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In the Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution
the combobox for display is populated with names that are meaningful even when a driver isn't loaded and even when the WMI information isn't populated.

Where is it getting things like "Mobile display"?

Answer (score 4):

It uses the VESA standard [DDC interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) to get the EDID data from the monitor.

Comment: That is not eniterly true.  My laptop display shows up as Mobile PC Display in windows7, but the EDID info from the the WMI interface doesn't have a name at all.